# How to apply a condition within a group

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

I have the following data:

```
  Group Hormone Damage    Score Greater   
 1 B     control damaged       4       1        
 2 B     control undamaged     4       1        
 3 B     JA      damaged       2       0       
 4 B     JA      undamaged     3       0  
 5 D     control damaged       2       0        
 6 D     control undamaged     1       0        
 7 D     JA      damaged       4       1        
 8 D     JA      undamaged     3       1
```

I have created the column "Greater" manually. Essentially, it asks "Within a group, which damaged score value is greater?" The greater value is assigned 1, the lesser 0.

How do I create some code to do this for me? I've tried with the following dplyr code, but with no success:

```
df%>% group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(Greater1 = if_else(Score>Score, 0,1))
```

If this question has already been asked, please let me know, because I can't find a similar one.

Comment: Note that `Score>Score` is always `FALSE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not have an issue with ties, you can simply do

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(Group, Damage) %>% 
 mutate(new = as.integer(Score == max(Score)))
```

which gives

> ```
> # A tibble: 8 x 6
> # Groups:   Group, Damage [4]
>   Group Hormone Damage    Score Greater   new
>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>     <int>   <int> <int>
> 1 B     control damaged       4       1     1
> 2 B     control undamaged     4       1     1
> 3 B     JA      damaged       2       0     0
> 4 B     JA      undamaged     3       0     0
> 5 D     control damaged       2       0     0
> 6 D     control undamaged     1       0     0
> 7 D     JA      damaged       4       1     1
> 8 D     JA      undamaged     3       1     1
> ```

Comment: Excellent, thank-you! I don't have an issue with ties in this dataset, but I may in another dataset. Is there a way to assign a value to ties?

Comment: Above method will assign 1 to all maximum values. So if you have a tie, then It will assign 1 to both

Comment: Ok, great! Is there a way to alternate 0 and 1 so that ties are distributed across both groups evenly? (This might be another question)

Answer (score 3):

A base R option using `ave`

```
df$Greater <- with(df, as.numeric(Score == ave(Score, Group, Damage, FUN = max)))

df
#  Group Hormone    Damage Score Greater
#1     B control   damaged     4       1
#2     B control undamaged     4       1
#3     B      JA   damaged     2       0
#4     B      JA undamaged     3       0
#5     D control   damaged     2       0
#6     D control undamaged     1       0
#7     D      JA   damaged     4       1
#8     D      JA undamaged     3       1
```

which can also be written as

```
df$Greater <- with(df, ave(Score, Group, Damage, FUN = function(x) x == max(x)))
```

---

Or to continue the `if_else` approach you were trying

```
library(dplyr)
df%>% 
  group_by(Group, Damage) %>% 
  mutate(Greater1 = if_else(Score==max(Score), 1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, new := as.integer(Score == max(Score)), .(Group, Damage)]
```